# Update Trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have two tables call it **Table_A** and **Table_B**. I want to create a trigger such that whenever the **`payment`** field in **Table_A** is updated a new record should be inserted into **Table_B** to show the difference in the amounts of total payments before and total payments now. The two table are below :

**Table_A**

```
A_id | payment |
 1   |  1000   |
 2   |   200   |
```

**Table_B**

```
B_id |  difference |
```

My implementation of the trigger is below. I am unsure how to calculate this difference:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_Difference
ON Table_A
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Difference as INT
 DECLARE @PreviousDiff as INT

 BEGIN
    SELECT @PreviousDiff = SUM(payment)
    FROM Table_A
 END

 if update(payment)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Difference = ***don't know what to put here*** 
        FROM inserted

        INSERT INTO Table_B (difference) VALUES (@Difference)
    END
END
```

Comment: Hint:  The difference in the total payments *before* adding this payment and *after* adding this payment is equal to exactly one payment, the most recent one.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here: `SELECT @Difference = .... FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution of this problem is to use the OUTPUT clause in the stored procedure which does the updating or just adapt this method to your needs.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE_A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TABLE_A
IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE_B') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TABLE_B
IF OBJECT_ID('sp_Payment_Update') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC sp_Payment_Update
GO

CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
    A_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Payment INT
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (
    B_ID INT ,
    OldPayment INT,
    NewPayment INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (1000),(1200)
GO

CREATE PROC sp_Payment_Update
    @A_ID INT,
    @Payment INT
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE TABLE_A
    SET Payment = @Payment
        OUTPUT
            INSERTED.A_ID,
            DELETED.Payment,
            INSERTED.Payment
        INTO TABLE_B
    WHERE A_ID = @A_ID


    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
END
GO

EXEC sp_Payment_Update 1, 1500
```

The update code itself will log as many changes you make with it in **TABLE_B** also you can put a UpdateDate column in **TABLE_B** with a default value of **GETDATE()** to make it more informative.